# Can't use certain characters in a regex

Tags: php, regex

```
if(!eregi("^([0-9a-z_\[\]\*\- ])+$", $subuser))
    $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
```

Can anybody tell me why it is not allowing characters such as `-` and `*`?

```
if(!eregi("^([0-9a-z])+$", $subuser))
    $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
```

That is the original piece of code. A friend changed it to the top piece and it will allow a-z and 0-9 but it wont allow the other characters I need it to. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For bracket expressions:

To include a literal `]` in the list, make it the first character (following a possible `^`).  To include a literal `-`, make it the first or last character, or  the second endpoint of a range.  To use a literal `-` as the first endpoint of a range, enclose it in `[.` and `.]` to make it a collating element (see below).  With the exception of these and some combinations using `[` (see next paragraphs), all other special characters, including `\`, lose their special significance within a bracket expression.

So this should do what you want:

```
"^([]0-9a-z_[* -])+$"
```

Answer (score 7):

Your regex uses PCRE syntax, so you have to use preg_match() instead of eregi().

Try this code instead:

```
else if (!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z_\[\]* -])+$/i", $subuser)) {
$form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the ereg family of functions - they are slower and, if I recall correctly, will eventually be deprecated.

This should fix it

```
if ( preg_match( "/^[^0-9a-z_\[\]* -]$/i", $subuser )
{
    $form->setError( $field, "* Username not alphanumeric" );
}
```

Comment: yep - they are going to be removed altogether in PHP6. Best to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

even using preg_* functions the pattern needs to be wrapped in nonalphanum delimiters:

"~^([0-9a-z_[]*- ])+$~"